# Gstreamer with gst-omx Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian

I compiled the gstreamer with gst-omx following this tutorial: http://www.onepitwopi.com/raspberry-pi/gstreamer-1-2-on-the-raspberry-pi/

Everything went fine and in the end when i ran gst-inspect-1.0 | grep omx I got:

```
omx:  omxmpeg2videodec: OpenMAX MPEG2 Video Decoder
omx:  omxmpeg4videodec: OpenMAX MPEG4 Video Decoder
omx:  omxh263dec: OpenMAX H.263 Video Decoder
omx:  omxh264dec: OpenMAX H.264 Video Decoder
omx:  omxtheoradec: OpenMAX Theora Video Decoder
omx:  omxvp8dec: OpenMAX VP8 Video Decoder
omx:  omxmjpegdec: OpenMAX MJPEG Video Decoder
omx:  omxvc1dec: OpenMAX WMV Video Decoder
omx:  omxh264enc: OpenMAX H.264 Video Encoder
omx:  omxanalogaudiosink: OpenMAX Analog Audio Sink
omx:  omxhdmiaudiosink: OpenMAX HDMI Audio Sink
```

Everything seems fine but when I try to use gst-launch-1.0 with the omx decoder I get nothing.

This pipeline runs fine(but really slow so I closed it in the middle):

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=./h264_720p_hp_5.1_6mbps_ac3_planet.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! eglglessink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Got context from element 'eglglessink0': gst.egl.EGLDisplay=context, display=(Gst    EGLDisplay)NULL;
Redistribute latency...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstEglGlesSink:eglglessink0: A lot of buffers are being dropped.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesink.c(2791): gst_base_sink_is_too_late (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstEglGlesSink:eglglessink0:
There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow.
^Chandling interrupt.
Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
Execution ended after 0:00:07.915424268
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Then I try the same pipeline with omx I get this:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=h264_720p_hp_5.1_6mbps_ac3_planet.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! omxh264dec ! eglglessink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Got context from element 'eglglessink0': gst.egl.EGLDisplay=context, display=(GstEGLDisplay)NULL;
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)5.1, profile=(string)high, codec_data=(buffer)01640033ffe1001867640033ac34e2805005ba10001974f004c4b408f18318a801008468eebce5531cc305d2628d13080214868783a1c0d04e12142c0ac0da02fe10042ad35e9e850b748c778a1410088b172105449ca3050e204448b20a4d8a081827090809848541dc4290a43164215a201900cae8340f81e86f03300b6017002ac05981d61a07802a8400a902087404700bc010506e036404b811805902e07203e0087ff85b, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)24000/1001, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)5.1, profile=(string)high, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)24000/1001, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstOMXH264Dec-omxh264dec:omxh264dec-omxh264dec0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)5.1, profile=(string)high, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, framerate=(fraction)24000/1001, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstOMXH264Dec-omxh264dec:omxh264dec-omxh264dec0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)bt709, framerate=(fraction)24000/1001
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstEglGlesSink:eglglessink0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)1280, height=(int)720, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, colorimetry=(string)bt709, framerate=(fraction)24000/1001
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstOMXH264Dec-omxh264dec:omxh264dec-omxh264dec0: Could not configure supporting library.
Additional debug info:
gstomxvideodec.c(1505): gst_omx_video_dec_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstOMXH264Dec-omxh264dec:omxh264dec-omxh264dec0:
Unable to reconfigure output port
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstEglGlesSink:eglglessink0.GstPad:sink: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstOMXH264Dec-omxh264dec:omxh264dec-omxh264dec0.GstPad:src: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstOMXH264Dec-omxh264dec:omxh264dec-omxh264dec0.GstPad:sink: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:src: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:sink: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQTDemux:qtdemux0.GstPad:video_0: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQTDemux:qtdemux0.GstPad:audio_0: caps = NULL
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I think this is the most important part of this error:

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstOMXH264Dec-omxh264dec:omxh264dec-omxh264dec0: Could not configure supporting library.
```

but couldn't find any reference to this error...

Tried to make check the gst-omx but it doesn't have any check routine.

Can anyone shed some light in this matter?

Thanks a lot!
=D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution:

I forgot to increase the memory of the gpu, so my 720p video decoding didn't have enough memory to run. The easy fix is just to add

```
gpu_mem=128
```

to /boot/config.txt and reboot.